# appspec.yml failed on AfterInstall Failed ScriptMissing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am trying to setup CI-CD using AWS Source, CodeBuild and CodeDeploy(process of pipeline). Right now I am stuck at the step of deploy. individually `CodeDeploy` is work fine but if i'm using pipeline with tree step like(source->codebuild->codedeploy) getting error this

```
scripts/install_dependencies
Script does not exist at specified location: /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/492e547b-60d1-4304-906c-0cf6784e906a/d-6Z0CFIDSZ/deployment-archive/scripts/install_dependencies
```

for more understanding:-
[image]

codedeploy-agent.log

> 2019-05-15 03:53:09 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(531)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Error during perform: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::ScriptError - Script does not exist at specified location: /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/492e547b-60d1-4304-906c-0cf6784e906a/d-XTTKE28SZ/deployment-archive/scripts/start_server.sh - /opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:119:in `block (2 levels) in execute'

Comment: @jogold can you help me?

Comment: Have you browsed to `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/492e547b-60d1-4304-906c-0cf6784e906a/d-XTTKE28SZ/deployment-archive/scripts/` to see what is or isn't there? Note that this is where your deployment scripts are run from - not from the eventual location your code is deployed to

Answer (score 0):

Go to your AWS console  and run the deployment manually through CodeDeploy application. Once I met this scenario even though file existed.